# How to download whole gmail as a pdf format in appscript gmail addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm using **card services** to make a **Gmail addon**. I want to develop a **download** feature on **button** clicks. When the user **clicks** the Button, I want to **download** the **email** as a **pdf**. I'm not getting any idea about it because we can not directly download **Gmail** on a button click maybe we have to use **third-party libraries**.

So, Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's fine but I want to download the email body as a pdf. Is this possible?